# Effective Java Item 44 - Where is the `DoubleToObjFunction` in the standard library?

Tags: java, functional-interface, effective-java

#### Background

In Effective Java at Item 44, the author recommended the use of standard functional interfaces (instead of defining custom ones). In relation to `java.util.function` package, the author:

- listed the six basic forms: `UnaryOperator<T>`, `BinaryOperator<T>`, `Predicate<T>`, `Function<T, R>`, `Supplier<T>`, `Consumer<T>`;
- explained that there are three variants to each of the six basic forms that operate on the primitive types, giving as examples `IntPredicate`, `LongBinaryOperator`, and `LongFunction<int[]>`;
- and in the next paragraph mentioned the following:

  > There are nine additional variants of the `Function` interface... If the source is a primitive and the result is an object reference, prefix Function with `SrcToObj`, for example `DoubleToObjFunction` (three variants).

#### Question

Where is this `DoubleToObjFunction` referred to by the author?

Notice in the third bullet point above that he used the words "nine additional variants", and hence could not have been referring the `DoubleFunction` since that would be the covered in the second bullet point.

I have tried a basic Google search of the function name in quotation, and also looked at the latest Java documentation on [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) but couldn't seem to find anything.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html

Comment: @Jorn does that mean there should be two additional errata to the book: (1) correcting the reference from`DoubleToObjFunction` to `DoubleFunction`; and (2) rephrasing "There are nine __*additional*__ variants..." becasue the `DoubleFunction` variant (specifically, `LongFunction<int[]>`) is mentioned in the preceding paragraph, and would not be "additional".

Comment: @yongjieyongjie The quote isn't really clear for those who can't refer to the book. Could you connect the dots *There are nine additional variants of the Function interface...* and complete the reference? Besides, that the three variants for `DoubleToObjFunction` could point to `DoubleFunction`, `DoubleToIntFunction` and `DoubleToLongFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no interfaces called DoubleToObjFunction,LongToObjFunction and IntToObjFunction  in Java 8,but interfaces called ToDoubleFunction,ToLongFunction and ToIntFunction which are not mentioned by the author in item 44. It maybe a errata.